# Angular 2 Select Menu Value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the value of this dropdown, but i am getting an empty string.

```
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="test()" autocomplete="off">
<divformGroupName="SignUpForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
         <select formControlName="helloworld" title="University">
           <option *ngFor="let firstname of names">{{firstname}}</option>
         </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div>
<button type="submit" name="action">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is the typescript file

```
 myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  list = [
    {"name": "A"},
    {"name": "B"},
    {"name": "C"},
  ];
  names: Array<string> = this.list.map(id => id.name);

  test(){
    console.log(this.myForm.controls['SignUpForm'].value['helloworld']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      SignUpForm: this._fb.group({
        helloworld: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
        ])]
    }),
    });
```

I cant get the value of the select menu. When i do console.log, i am getting an empty string.

Any Help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where is definitions of variable names ?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I updated my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/SelectControlValueAccessor-directive.html

You'll need to bind [ngValue] on your option tag to get the backing model to follow your view.

It would look like this then:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="test()" autocomplete="off">
<divformGroupName="SignUpForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
         <select formControlName="helloworld" title="University">
           <option *ngFor="let firstname of names" [ngValue]="firstname">{{firstname}}</option>
         </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div>
<button type="submit" name="action">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: To any onlookers:  this is nice, as before I had to manually capture the change event and update my form, as the hook was not working properly in reactive forms -- this was back in beta, however.  Glad to see it should be working now.

Comment: Yes you are right for select you need to set ngValue

Comment: It is still not working. I am getting empty string in console.

Comment: did you make @VolodymyrBilyachat change as well?  I think your `<divformGroupName="SignUpForm"> ` needs to be `<div [formGroupName]="SignUpForm">`

Comment: @chrispy yes i did that

Comment: @chrispy try  console.log(this.myForm.getRawValue());

Comment: `{
  "SignUpForm": {
    "firstName": "asdf",
    "lastName": "asdf",
    "email": "asdf",
    "password": ".kl",
    "confirmPassword": "asdf",
    "helloworld": ""
  }
}`  Everything else is working, except the helloworld select menu

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat My code is working perfectly in the plunker, it is just not working on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, use `ngValue` like so:

```
<option *ngFor="let firstname of names" [ngValue]="firstname">
```

Otherwise the only issue to me seems to be a missing space on this line:

```
<divformGroupName="SignUpForm">
```

which should be

```
<div formGroupName="SignUpForm">
```

I made a plunker of your exact code, and it seems to be working fine with the above adjustments. Just if you want to double check the working code, here is the

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cB44v1hUqFqEOR41vf3m?p=preview)

Comment: @SoftwareNinja, did this answer help you? :)

Comment: No still not working for me. All other input fields are working, except the Select menu. It is just blank, doesnt change `{
  "SignUpForm": {
    "firstName": "asdf",
    "lastName": "asdf",
    "email": "asdf",
    "password": ".kl",
    "confirmPassword": "asdf",
    "helloworld": ""
  }
}`

Comment: I copied my code to the plunker, it is working there. It is just not working on my local machine. Do you think it dependency issue?

Comment: There must be something going on elsewhere in your app, yes, but what that might be is somewhat impossible to say from where I'm sitting... Sounds strange though that everything else works except the select. Hmm...

Comment: Yeah i am not sure either, I gotta dig deeper and see what is the issue.